Cannot merge Lora weights back to the Flux Dev base model
I have a Flux-Dev base model which has been trained with the LoRA technique using the SimpleTuner framework (https://github.com/bghira/SimpleTuner/blob/main/documentation/quickstart/FLUX.md). The training process has generated checkpoint folders containing the following files:

optimizer.bin
pytorch_lora_weights.safetensors
scheduler.bin
random_states_0.pkl
training_state-mydataset.json
training_state.json

I want to load the Flux-dev base model and the LoRA weights from one of the checkpoints, and merge the LoRA weights into the base model.
Following the LoRA documentation (here https://huggingface.co/docs/peft/main/en/developer_guides/lora), I tried the following:
from peft import PeftModel
from diffusers import FluxTransformer2DModel

lora_path = <path_to_checkpoint_folder>
base_model = FluxTransformer2DModel.from_pretrained(<local_path_to_flux_model>,subfolder=‘transformer’)
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, lora_path)
model.merge_and_unload()

I get the following error:
ValueError: Can’t find ‘adapter_config.json’ at <path_to_checkpoint_folder>’
There is indeed no such file in there. How can I load the Lora weights and merge them to the model in this case? Is there another way?
